# Why query returns same objects and implement twice query to database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a class User.

```
class User:
  def __ init__(self):
      pass

  def other_method(self):
      some_code
```

I need to query the database:

```
id = 10 # let be (conditionally)
a = session.query(User).first(User.id=id)
b = session.query(User).first(User.id=id)
```

In this case returned objects (a and b) are same - id(a) == id(b) and even hash(a) == hash(b). Also request is made twice for same objects. 
Is this behavior always guaranteed?

Comment: `Query.first()` does not accept filter criterion arguments and `first(User.id=id)` is a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

You call the query method twice so it will just do two different query.
To avoid this issue you could create your own manager.

```py
class QueryManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.alreadyQuery = {}

    def queryById(self, id):
        if id in self.alreadyQuery:
            return self.alreadyQuery[id]
        user = session.query(User).first(User.id=id)
        self.alreadyQuery[id] = user
        return user
```

Comment: SQLA Query API provides this out of the box with `Query.get()`.